# Check if user navigated to another view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a simple game that begins a timer when the game starts. The app has navigation controllers in place. The problem is that users can navigate away from the game and the timer will continue to countdown in the background of the app.

Is there a way to check if a segue was performed so that I can stop the game and the timer? Here's my current function used to count the timer down:

```
func Counting(){

    if timerCount == 0 // OR if user navigates away from game
    {
        timerCount = 7
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timerRunning = false

        endTurn()
    }
    else
    {
        self.timerRunning = true
        timerCount--
        timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
        print(timerCount)
    }

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! What you're thinking of is the prepareForSegue method! Anytime you perform a segue, this method will get called just before you leave the screen. Here's how you'd integrate it with your code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

   self.timerRunning = false


    // If you need do to logic with your destination VC before load
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as destinationVCType
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What exactly does this do? Sorry! I'm a little lost

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It triggers before any segue is preformed! So you can put your timer code inside of it. But I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Oooh! Perfect! Thanks for the info!

Comment: And I can put my Counting function inside the prepareForSegue function?

Comment: I wouldn't put the entire counting function within the prepareForSegue, but just a line of code that STOPS the count. So from what I understand of your code, self.timerRunning = false, or timerCount = 0?

Comment: Thanks! I understand the concept now. It works great!!